# How to extract the response of an HTTP API in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api, http

I called an HTTP API and got this as a respone

```
{"balance":0}
```

How do I use rails to extract and get just '0'?

stox

FYI I used the curb gem (curl) to call API calls...if that's of any help

Comment: see my answer. It may help you.

Answer (score 0):

It is a hash value. So treat it as simple as a Hash

```
{"balance" => 0}.each{ |k, v| puts v }
```

And If the response HASH has only element, You can do like

```
{"balance" => 0}.values.first
```